# My readme is readable in bitbucket but not in packagist

Tags: git, github, composer-php, bitbucket, packagist

I created my first composer package. After several problems (like autoload, versions, etc.), I managed to make something functional.

My last problem is that my readme.md is readable on my BitBucket repo but not in my packagist "page". I tried to let only a few basic lines in case it was a syntax error but it didn't work. Is there a known (or unknown) conflict between packagist and BitBucket (all packages I saw was only on GitHub)?

My packagist url: https://packagist.org/packages/mrdebug/crudgen

My BitBucket url: https://bitbucket.org/mrdebug/crudgen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Packagist only loads README data from GitHub.

The only trace I can find in the source code is [in a function called `updateGitHubInfo`](https://github.com/composer/packagist/blob/dd0dee3a687d3726c334ab773150bc8ee184d03d/src/Packagist/WebBundle/Package/Updater.php#L459-L472), which hard-codes GitHub's domain when it retrieves README data:

```php
private function updateGitHubInfo(...) {
    // ...
    $readme = $rfs->getContents('github.com', $baseApiUrl.'/readme', false, $opts);
    // ...
}
```